# My script automatically add '\r' and $'\r on every line. how can I remove $'\r from string?

Tags: scripting, ftp

My script automatically add '\r' and $'\r on every line.

how can i remove $'\r from string?

```
[root@a]# sh -x ./ftp.sh

+ HOST=$'0.0.00.2\r'

+ USER=$'root\r'

+ PASSWD=$'204\r

+ $'\r'
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to know exactly where you are writing the script. Sometimes writing it in Windows system and copying it to a UNIX machine generates this extra /r (line ending).

Some platforms support windows to UNIX command to convert the file to unix-style line endings. Therefore if you stick to UNIX based text editor problem might be overcomed.

Thanks
Syed Ayaz Mahmud

Comment: Thanks Ayaz. yes you are correct. I am writing my script in Windows system with Notepad ++ and then upload it to my Linux server. I am now editing with vi editor. Thanks for your suggestion.